# Duplicating a slide in PowerPoint presentation

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

How to duplicate a particular slide using Excel VBA?

Comment: can you post what you have tried in your coding efforts to duplicate the slide? If you post the code you've tried and where you are stuck, we can help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Duplicate
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This will duplicate and move slide 1:

```
Sub Duplicate_And_Move_Slide()

    Dim oPPT As Object
    Dim oPresentation As Object
    Dim oSlide As Object

    Set oPPT = CreatePPT
    Set oPresentation = oPPT.presentations.Open( _
        "<full path to your PP Presentation")

    With oPresentation.slides(1)
        .Duplicate
        .MoveTo 3
    End With

End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : CreatePPT
' Purpose   : Creates an instance of Powerpoint and passes the reference back.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function CreatePPT(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpPPT As Object

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case PowerPoint is not running. '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpPPT = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of PowerPoint. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                                 '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If

    oTmpPPT.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreatePPT = oTmpPPT

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreatePPT."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```